# PHP XAMPP log interpretation - server shutting down / connecton lost from browser

Tags: php, apache, xmpp

Okay, first of all I understand and ... permit ... you all to laugh: I have a local server running php 4,4 / apache / mysql - installed with xampp distribution. Just simply haven't got the time to upgrade all the code that has been serving me for years and is still serving me well :-)

To the issue - I can't make a try/catch ... beeeecause of the old php version. I have a script that parses a dir and to a lot of things to all the files ... and after several 100 thousand files over the years without problems ... I now find that the server shuts down / browser looses connection probably because of a single file ... but for my life I can't figure out which. So thought maybe I could figure it out through the error log. But ... I didn't learn much - and thought I might ask some wise guys here if there is anything I can learn from the following from my error log - regarding maybe what function/file or whatever it is that causes the breaking...:

```
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:26 2017] [crit] (22)Invalid argument: unable to replace stderr with error_log
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:26 2017] [crit] (2)No such file or directory: unable to replace stderr with /dev/null
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:26 2017] [notice] Apache/2.0.54 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.0.54 OpenSSL/0.9.8 PHP/4.4.0 mod_autoindex_color configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:26 2017] [notice] Server built: Jul 28 2005 18:10:37
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:26 2017] [notice] Parent: Created child process 5384
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:27 2017] [notice] Child 5384: Child process is running
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:27 2017] [notice] Child 5384: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:27 2017] [notice] Child 5384: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:36 2017] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225725 -- Restarting.
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:36 2017] [crit] (22)Invalid argument: unable to replace stderr with error_log
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:36 2017] [crit] (2)No such file or directory: unable to replace stderr with /dev/null
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:36 2017] [notice] Apache/2.0.54 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.0.54 OpenSSL/0.9.8 PHP/4.4.0 mod_autoindex_color configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:36 2017] [notice] Server built: Jul 28 2005 18:10:37
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:36 2017] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3136
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:36 2017] [notice] Child 3136: Child process is running
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:36 2017] [notice] Child 3136: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Feb 14 20:47:36 2017] [notice] Child 3136: Starting 250 worker threads.
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it ... filesize() was failing (silent aparently) for some file(s). Ran it w/o this function and it worked. Case closed...

Edit: strange though ... filesize() suddenly fails on all files. And they are local. Subdir to the htdocs folder ... and the top level folder to this structure is set to all my users to have full control of this folder and all subfolders... weird...